# How to handle the Exceptions in JSP, when session expires?

Tags: jsp, session, struts

I'm working on struts1.3.8. The JSP page contains scriptlet to iterate the data in the session. Once the user opens the page and not performing any operation till the session expires and then next refreshing it is throwing `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

So how to handle that exception and how to make the session alive?

Comment: That's just a bug in your code. You should fix your code to treat cases where the object is `null`, instead of relying on it to never be `null`.

Comment: sometimes when the session do not expires also the session attributes are giving null, when they are trying to access. But sometimes working fine. What would be the problem??? with session???

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on the existence of a *well-known* attribute in session.

Set this when the session is first created.

```
session.setAttribute("well-known-attribute", "abcd");
```

In your JSP, check if this attribute exists before you do any iterations.

```
if(session.getAttribute("well-known-attribute") != null) {
    // iterate others now
} else {
    session.setAttribute("well-known-attribute", "abcd");
    // now add the other attributes.
}
```

A new session will [always be created](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29) if

- There isn't one already **AND**
- There is a request associated.

Comment: Hi Adarshr, Is there any way of redirecting user to some exception page when the currently refreshing page is throwing Exception???

Comment: You can declare error pages in your `web.xml`. `<error-page>
<exception-type>java.lang.NullPointerException</exception-type>
<location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>`. But I would suggest handling it rather than just redirecting to some error page.

Comment: when the session expires, the scriptlet will throw exception. In that case redirecting him to some error page will make sense i think.. Is it correct???

Comment: I think it'll work for now. The better option is to send him to the homepage whenever you find that `well-known-attribute` is `null`. Try doing with websites such as gmail or facebook. Sign in, leave it open for a few hours, come back and refresh. You'll go to the homepage/sign-in page rather than seeing an error page.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. So i have to redirect user to login page once the session expires???? is there any way of making session alive, See gmail,will not redirect to login page even you make it idle for hours and hours...

Comment: That is because gmail has a long session timeout value. Try doing that with a banking website.

Comment: That sounds not good. how can we make a long time session for the banking websites. that is not a secure one. Can we make the session alive in JSP????

Comment: You can set `<session-timeout>` in `web.xml` to a long value if you want it to last a longer duration.

Comment: I did it. But before the session expires only the jsp page throwing the NullPointerException. What would be the reason???

Comment: How do you know it is "before"?

Comment: From this forum,someone asked this question.I got the answer for that. But now i don't have the same problem. I have some other issue. I said you in last reply

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11022/discussion-between-mr-chowdary-and-adarshr)