# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException when JSP page refreshes, How to Handle?

Tags: jsp, session, nullpointerexception

In my jsp page some pure java code there i.e, scriptlet. After a long time when refresh it then it is throwing

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Sometimes not for a long time also it is throwing same Exception. and the JSP page is displaying empty page. So the user have only one option is Logout. So to avoid that and redirect him to one page that is error page. How to do it ?

Comment: Based on the information you have provided no-one here (unless they have a very good crystal ball) is going to be able to answer that. You need to provide the full stack trace and the relevant code from the JSP.

Comment: You have asked same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499683/how-to-handle-the-exceptions-in-jsp-when-session-expires

Comment: There answers are not relevant to my issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form What I get here is, on refresh session values might be getting NULL after a certain period of time and thus resulting in `NullPointerException` .

Create a JSP page called error page and set

```
<%@page isErrorPage="true" %>
```

In other JSP pages,

```
<%@page errorPage="error.jsp" %>
```

So, It will redirect to this page when any Run time error occurs in your JSP.

Note: This won't redirect to error page if JSP has compile time error.